How do I extract the number after the "of" Text in Cypress
Im new to cypress and im trying extract the number at the end of the following text into a variable.  The element is "cy.get(':nth-child(3) > span')" and the text is "1-44 of 44",  i need to extract the number at the end after the of text and the value could be 1 to 1000
I took the code from another question but it doesnt answer my question as there is more that 1 number in the string.
I would really appreciate some help.
cy.get(':nth-child(3) > span').invoke('text').as('NoR')
  .then((NoR) => {
    var fullNoR = NoR;
    var pattern = /[0-9]+/g;
    var NewNOR = fullNoR.match(pattern);
    console.log(NewNOR);
  });


How do you plan on using the found number? Will it only be used in the same .then() block? Or will you need to access it in another block/Cypress Chain/test?

You may wish to try to match the regular expression (?<= of )(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}|1000)\d+$. Demo

The regex pattern is matching any number in the string "1-44 of 44", and there are three parts of the string that match.
Your console.log(NewNOR) shows an array of these three numbers: ['1', '44', '44'], so you want the third one
cy.get(':nth-child(3) > span').invoke('text')
.then((text) => {
  const pattern = /[0-9]+/g
  const numbers = text.match(pattern)   // extracts 3 results
  console.log(numbers)                  //  ['1', '44', '44']
  const total = numbers[2]              // third result
  return +total                         // putting + in front to extract number
})
.should('eq', 44)



To just get the last digit, add $ to the pattern - this extracts just the digits at the end of the text.
cy.get(':nth-child(3) > span').invoke('text')
.then((text) => {
  const pattern = /[0-9]+$/g
  const total = text.match(pattern)[0]   // extracts 1 result only
  console.log(total)                     // '44'
  return +total                         
})
.should('eq', 44)


parseInt(text.split("of")[1])

You don't have to parse the int out of it, but I would.

Hi Pat,  Thank you for your response.  Its failing as text is not defined,  please could you give me the full code to the question as im confused still.  Thanks in advance

text is whatever variable the text "1-44 of 44" is
ie
parseInt("1-44 of 44".split("of")[1]) 
will equal 44
So for you
parseInt(NewNOR.split("of")[1])

Thanks to both of you.  Both scenarios work fine for me
